# Tiny CC gotoxy in command prompt

Tags: c, tcc

I'd like to develop character based program with Tiny C Compiler.
The putc works fine, but I want to print the character in a specific place on the character screen. Like in turbo pascal with gotoxy. Is there such a possibility?
I'm looking through a bunch of header files, but couldn't find one.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  //    gotoxy(1,15); // ???????    
  putc(65,stdout); 
}
```

Comment: Use `printf("\033[%d;%dH", 15, 1);` if you are on a VT100 compatible terminal.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. It is a simple command line under windows 10.

Comment: But you can use the PowerShell, isn't it?

Comment: succeeded! was missing system(" "); from the beginning of the program. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `system`? Why do you need it?

Comment: I don't know, but that's how it works. I'll look into why I need to.